# RecyclerView flashing data at start turning the rows invisible

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

In some devices the recyclerview are flashing items and nothing more, after that, appear from items in row. I can't debug that because in emulator and my phone it doesn't happen.

Has anyone ever experienced that?

[image]

**The correct thing would be to keep as the follow img:**

[image]

I'm creating the RecyclerView as below, in SubItemsActivity:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    subMainList = ArrayList()

    subMainList = db.listSubItems("AND id_main_item=$mainId")

    layoutManagerRecycler = LinearLayoutManager(this)
    subMainItemsRecycler.layoutManager = layoutManagerRecycler
    subMainItemsRecycler.addItemDecoration(DividerItemDecoration(this, 1))

    var subMainAdapter = SubMainAdapter(this, subMainList, this, activate)
    subMainAdapter.setHasStableIds(true)
    subMainItemsRecycler.adapter = subMainAdapter
}
```

The recyclerView layout is here:
I have two ConstraintLayouts, the main is the first, with id "prioritize_edit", the other layout with id "prioritize_sub" will not appear in the image example.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/prioritize_edit"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/counter"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:paddingStart="4dp"
            android:paddingEnd="2dp"
            android:paddingVertical="7.5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
            android:background="#BFBFBF"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/arrows"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" >
        </TextView>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/arrows"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_arrow_bottom"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_width="15dp"
            android:paddingEnd="1dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/counter"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/check_item"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        </ImageView>

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/check_item"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:layout_gravity="start|center_vertical"
            android:gravity="start|center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginStart="3dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/arrows"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/color_picker"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/color_picker"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@null"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="13dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="13dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/check_item"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/list_subitem"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/list_subitem"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-black"
            android:textColor="@color/text_gray"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/color_picker"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/menu_subitem"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/menu_subitem"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:paddingEnd="8dp"
            android:src="@drawable/round_more_vert_black_36"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/list_subitem"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/draggable_subitem"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/draggable_subitem"
        android:layout_width="42dp"
        android:layout_height="42dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_marginVertical="0dp"
        android:src="@drawable/icon_draggable"
        android:background="@null"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/menu_subitem"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/prioritize_sub"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp">


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/prioritizer_button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-black"
        android:text="@string/prioritize"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:alpha="0.80"
        android:paddingHorizontal="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/counter_invisible"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/counter_invisible"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:paddingHorizontal="10dp"
        android:paddingVertical="7.5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
        android:background="#BFBFBF"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/prioritizer_button"/>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

My Adapter is this:

```
class SubMainAdapter(
    var activity: SubMainActivity,
    var items: MutableList<SubItems>,
    var clickListener: OnSubMainItemClickListener,
    var activate: Boolean
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<SubMainViewHolder>(){

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return items.size
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): SubMainViewHolder {

        val itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(
            R.layout.layout_subitem_view,
            parent,
            false
        )
        val viewHolder = SubMainViewHolder(itemView)

        return viewHolder
    }

    @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: SubMainViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.initialize(
            activity, items[position], clickListener, items.size,
            items,
            position
        )

        if (activate) {
            holder.dragButton.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            holder.check_item.visibility = View.GONE
            holder.menuButton.visibility = View.GONE
        } else {
            holder.dragButton.visibility = View.GONE
            holder.check_item.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            holder.menuButton.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        }

        holder.dragButton.setOnTouchListener { v, event ->
            if(event.actionMasked== MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                v.performClick()
                activity.touchHelper?.startDrag(holder)
            }
            false
        }
    }

    override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
        val subItems: SubItems = items[position]
        return subItems.id.toLong()
    }

    override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
        return position
    }
}

class SubMainViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){
    var subMainItem = itemView.list_subitem
    var counter = itemView.counter
    var arrows = itemView.arrows
    var counterInvisible = itemView.counter_invisible
    var prioritizeSub = itemView.prioritize_sub
    var prioritizerButton = itemView.prioritizer_button
    var prioritizeEdit = itemView.prioritize_edit
    var check_item = itemView.check_item
    var deleteButton = R.id.trash_subitem
    var menuButton = itemView.menu_subitem
    var dragButton = itemView.draggable_subitem
    var color_picker = itemView.color_picker

    fun initialize(
        activity: SubMainActivity,
        item: SubItems,
        action: OnSubMainItemClickListener,
        sizeArrayItems: Int,
        listItems: MutableList<SubItems>,
        position: Int
    ){
//        var counterValue: String = item.list_order.toString()
//        var digitsNumber: Int = sizeArrayItems.toString().length
//        while (counterValue.length<digitsNumber){
//            counterValue = "0$counterValue"
//        }
        var counterValue: String = item.path_index

        subMainItem.setText(item.sub_item)
        counterInvisible.text = "$counterValue"
        counter.text = "$counterValue"

        counter.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#a5a5a5"))
        counter.background.alpha = if(item.max_level==0) 0 else (255*item.level)/item.max_level
        arrows.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#a5a5a5"))
        arrows.background.alpha = if(item.max_level==0) 0 else (255*item.level)/item.max_level

        val prevItem = if(position <= listItems.size){listItems[position]}else{if(position-1 <= listItems.size){listItems[position]}else{listItems[position - 1]}}
        val childs = item.direct_childs
        val nextItem = if(position >= listItems.size){listItems[position]}else{if(position+1 >= listItems.size){listItems[position]}else{listItems[position + 1]}}

        if(childs==0){
            arrows.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_arrow_right)
        }else{
            if(nextItem.visibility == 0){
                arrows.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_arrow_right)
            }else {
                arrows.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_arrow_bottom)
            }
            arrows.setOnClickListener {
                action.toggleSubItems(item, adapterPosition, itemView)
            }
            counter.setOnClickListener {
                action.toggleSubItems(item, adapterPosition, itemView)
            }

        }

        if (item.prioritizeButton){
            prioritizeSub.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            val prioritizeString = activity.getString(R.string.prioritize)
            val finalStr = String.format(prioritizeString, item.path_index)
            prioritizerButton.text = finalStr
            prioritizerButton.setOnClickListener{
                action.onPrioritizeItemsClick(item)
            }
            prioritizeEdit.visibility = View.GONE
        }else{
            prioritizeSub.visibility = View.GONE
            prioritizeEdit.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        }

        val param = itemView.layoutParams as RecyclerView.LayoutParams
        if (item.visibility==1) {
            param.height = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
            param.width = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
            itemView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        } else {
            itemView.visibility = View.GONE
            param.height = 0
            param.width = 0
        }
        itemView.layoutParams = param


        if (item.checked==Constants.TRUE){
            check_item.isChecked = true
            subMainItem.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(activity, (R.color.checked)))
            counter.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(activity, (R.color.checked)))
            subMainItem.apply {
                paintFlags = paintFlags or Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG
            }
            counter.apply {
                paintFlags = paintFlags or Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG
            }
        }else{
            check_item.isChecked = false
            subMainItem.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(activity, (R.color.text_grayer)))
            counter.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(activity, (R.color.text_gray_darker)))
            subMainItem.apply {
                paintFlags = paintFlags and Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG.inv()
            }
            counter.apply {
                paintFlags = paintFlags and Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG.inv()
            }
        }
        check_item.setOnClickListener{
            action.onCheckItemClick(item, adapterPosition, itemView)
        }

        menuButton.setOnClickListener{
            val popup = PopupMenu(activity, menuButton)
            popup.inflate(R.menu.submain_options)
            popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(object : PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener {
                override fun onMenuItemClick(menuItem: MenuItem): Boolean {
                    when (menuItem.itemId) {
                        R.id.trash_subitem -> {
                            action.onExcludeItemClick(item, adapterPosition)
                            return true
                        }
                        R.id.add_sub_subitem -> {
                            action.onAddChildItemClick(item, adapterPosition)
                            return true
                        }
                        R.id.prioritize_sub_subitem -> {
                            action.manageDragButtons(true, item.id, item.direct_childs)
                            return true
                        }
                        else -> return false
                    }
                }
            })
            popup.show()
        }

        val textWatcher = object : TextWatcher {
            override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {}
            override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {}
            override fun onTextChanged(
                text: CharSequence?,
                start: Int,
                before: Int,
                count: Int
            ) {
                action.onKeyDownItem(item, itemView, text)
            }
        }
        subMainItem.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher)

        color_picker.adapter = CustomSpinnerAdapter(
            color_picker.context,
            listOf(
                SpinnerData(R.drawable.white_arrow),
                SpinnerData(R.drawable.red_arrow),
                SpinnerData(R.drawable.orange_arrow),
                SpinnerData(R.drawable.yellow_arrow),
                SpinnerData(R.drawable.green_arrow),
                SpinnerData(R.drawable.blue_arrow),
                SpinnerData(R.drawable.turquoise_arrow),
                SpinnerData(R.drawable.purple_arrow)
            )
        )
//        var checkSpinner: Int = 0
        color_picker.isSelected = false;
        color_picker.setSelection(item.color, false)
        color_picker.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
            override fun onItemSelected(
                adapterView: AdapterView<*>?,
                view: View,
                spinnerPosition: Int,
                l: Long
            ) {
//                if(++checkSpinner > 1) {
                    action.onSpinnerChange(item, spinnerPosition)
//                }
            }

            override fun onNothingSelected(adapterView: AdapterView<*>?) {
                return
            }
        }
    }
}

interface OnSubMainItemClickListener{
    fun onCheckItemClick(item: SubItems, position: Int, view: View)
    fun onExcludeItemClick(item: SubItems, position: Int)
    fun onAddChildItemClick(item: SubItems, position: Int)
    fun onPrioritizeItemsClick(item: SubItems)
    fun onKeyDownItem(item: SubItems, view: View, text: CharSequence?)
    fun onChangeItem(item: SubItems, view: View, text: CharSequence?)
    fun onSpinnerChange(item: SubItems, spinnerPosition: Int)
    fun manageDragButtons(activate: Boolean, parentId: Int, childs: Int)
    fun toggleSubItems(item: SubItems, position: Int, view: View)
}
```

As I'm using **setHasStableIds(true)** I've tried to change the getItemId function in adapter, but the problem remains. Has anyone had a similar problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It was a problem in OnItemSelectedListener from my spinner. The function inside it was always calling the database list, because of OnItemSelectedListener are called one first time when it is being created, I've uncommented the checkSpinner variable in Adapter to prevent this first call and now it has been solved.

```
    var checkSpinner: Int = 0
    color_picker.isSelected = false;
    color_picker.setSelection(item.color, false)
    color_picker.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
        override fun onItemSelected(
            adapterView: AdapterView<*>?,
            view: View,
            spinnerPosition: Int,
            l: Long
        ) {
            if(++checkSpinner > 1) {
                action.onSpinnerChange(item, spinnerPosition)
            }
        }

        override fun onNothingSelected(adapterView: AdapterView<*>?) {
            return
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

`onBindViewHolder()` will draw the views. You are having a lot of views visible in default case in the xml. All views that are going to be toggled with visibility must have visibility as gone or invisible by default in the xml. `onBindViewHolder()` can control the visibility once views are loaded.

The issue is recycler inflates the view in `onCreateViewHolder()`, the views are visible. After this the data is set and `notifyDataSetChanged` is called. This will update the views as per the conditions in the `onBindViewHolder()` function. But, till this happens, you see the views. Since this takes small amount of time, you see flashing.

This will happen in devices which are having low memory or slower processing.

Comment: Mohit, this issue you've said looks like a temporary invisible rows, the rows would'nt be loaded correctly after a time?

Comment: That is the flashing issue. View loads, you see the views, then data is added to the list and notify is called. That's the reason you see the flicker/flashing.

Comment: If you just see the layout without adding any data, you will see that is exact replica of what you see of your xml design in default state.

Comment: Teorically, if I put a visibility gone on the prioritize_sub item, will it work then?

Comment: The views in the entire item must not be visible, then in theory you should not see the flashing.

Comment: The problem is not the flash, but the items that are being invisible after the flash...

Comment: i've updated my question with a printscreen as how the recyclerview should be

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232275/discussion-between-mohit-ajwani-and-alexandre9865).

Comment: I've called you there again